# Solving an equation with $\sin(x)$ in the exponent: $2^{\sin(x)} \cdot \cos(x) + 1 = 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Hi I need help with a trig problem:

I have $2^{\sin(x)} \cdot \cos(x) + 1$, 
and I need this to equal $1$ between $x = -3$ and $3$. 
I keep going in circles with substitution, etc.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

$2^{\sin x } \cos x +1 = 1 \implies 2^{\sin x } \cos x = 0 \implies 2^{\sin x}=0 \text{ or } \cos x =0$.

Can you deduce the solution from here?

Answer (score 1):

$2^{\sin(x)}\cos(x)+1 = 1$ gives $2^{\sin (x)}\cos(x)=0$, so that implies $x=\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi $ is the only solution, where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: That's $\cos$, not $\sin$.

Comment: Don't you want odd multiples of $\pi/2$?